# Bitbucket pipeline Permission denied with Laravel log file

Tags: laravel, bitbucket

Trying to run tests in Laravel in Bitbucket pipeline, but seems that once it fails, it tries to log the error into logs, and log file is not accessible

Bitbucket pipelines:

```
 script:
      - apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq unzip git
      - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
      - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --no-suggest --ignore-platform-req=ext-mongodb
      - cp .env.pipelines .env
      - export DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=1.18.0
      - export DOCKER_COMPOSE_URL=https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)
      - curl -L $DOCKER_COMPOSE_URL > docker-compose
      - chmod +x docker-compose
      - mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin
      - rm docker-compose.yml
      - cp docker-compose-bitbucket-pipeline.yml docker-compose.yml
      - ./vendor/bin/sail up -d
      - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan key:generate
```

Error:

```
he stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be 

opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2022-07-06.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied\n
The exception occurred while attempting to log: Customer paid successfully\n
```

Test body:

```
 $testCase->postJson(
        'api/v1/stripe/webhook',
        $payload,
        $this->getHeadersWithAuthorization($payload)
    );
```

Do you know how to fix it? Looks like I need to make storage folder is accessible and writable. But 'chmod -R 777 storage' in bitbucket pipelines doesn't help

Comment: What if you create the folder for it? `mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/logs`

Comment: - ./vendor/bin/sail root-shell
 - chmod -R 777 storage
that helped